# Blockquote button broken?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, markdown, formatting

```
Blockquote

Blockquote> HelloBlockquote

Blockquote
```

Above is an example of what I get when trying to create a blockquote using the toolbar button. I'm fairly sure this isn't what's meant to happen. I've also seen this in a [few places](https://askubuntu.com/posts/11941/revisions) on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a Chrome 6 (and above) bug - see [Blockquote glitch in editor in Chrome 6 and 7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63307/blockquote-glitch-in-editor-in-chrome-6) on Meta Stackoverflow.